# Can't make Fragment with RecyclerView work

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design, android-recyclerview

I have to create a list inside one of my Fragments but I cannot make recyclerview work, I was searching the internet whole day followed tutorials but could not figure out why its not working

row_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:name="com.streak.roadpoliceviolations.ViolationFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:context="com.streak.roadpoliceviolations.ViolationFragment"
    tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_violation" />
```

Adapter:

```
public class ViolationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViolationAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<ViolationItem> data= Collections.emptyList();

    public ViolationAdapter(List<ViolationItem> data) {
        //inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_violation, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ViolationItem current = data.get(position);
        holder.txt1.setText(current.txt1);
        holder.txt2.setText(current.txt2);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView txt1;
        TextView txt2;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txt1= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
            txt2= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt2);
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment class

```
public class ViolationFragment extends Fragment {

    private ViolationAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_violation_list, container, false);
        RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new ViolationAdapter(getActivity(),getData());
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        return view;
    }

    public static List<ViolationItem> getData() {
        List<ViolationItem> data = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] txts1 = {"AAA","BBB","CCC"};
        String[] txts2 = {"111","222","333"};
        for(int i=0; i<=txts1.length; i++) {
            ViolationItem c = new ViolationItem();
            c.txt1=txts1[i];
            c.txt2=txts2[i];
            data.add(c);
        }
        return data;
    }

    private List<ViolationItem> createList() {
        List<ViolationItem> data = new ArrayList<>();
        return data;
    }
}
```

Everything passes without a single warning BUT I cannot place this into the fragment container

In mine activity I'm calling the fragment with the following code

```
//Initial fragment
ViolationFragment frag = new ViolationFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction() .replace(R.id.frame_container, frag).commit();
```

Getting this error during the build

```
Error:(77, 75) error: incompatible types: ViolationFragment cannot be converted to Fragment
```

And if i change `frag` initialization `Fragment frag = new ViolationFragment();`
I get the same error.

How to finally fix this and make the fragment work?!

Comment: Check whether you're extending android.app.Fragment and not the support lib version

Comment: @fractalwrench I did check it and its extending from `android.app`

Comment: Try with 
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I remember you must use support library fragment to make it work. Please check and confirm.